# Algorithms for graphing functions

Tags: functions, inequality, algorithms, graphing-functions

I'm trying to find algorithms for creating graphs of functions (especially implicit) and inequalities, like what a graphing calculator does. Unfortunately, it's impossible to search for them since the words "graph" and "algorithm" together always lead to results about graph theory. Can someone send me in the direction of the algorithms I'm looking for?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_curve#Visualization_of_an_implicit_curve for a starting point.

Comment: Perhaps search for an algorithm to “plot” the function?